# spring-orm 3.2 require different JtaPlatform package, instead of hibernate-core 4.3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I have dependency to spring-orm 3.2 and hibernate-core 4.3.

My spring hibernate config:

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="my.domain.package"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>                
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In runtime i have exception

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform

in SpringSessionContext class. In my libs i see JtaPlatform in another hibernate package:

```
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform
```

(engine.transaction instead of service in package)

what am I doing wrong?

do not reproduced in 4.2.8 (JPA 2.0 instead of JPA 2.1), but I don't understand, why they broke comparability in minor release

Comment: This link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946044/spring-orm-3-2-require-different-jtaplatform-package-instead-of-hibernate-core

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the version of `hibernate-core` artifact you are using. `JtaPlatform` had been moved to another package since **4.3.0.Beta1**. Try using **4.2.8.Final**, it contains `JtaPlatform` in appropriate package.

Comment: it's works, but i don't understand, why they broke comparability and how to restore it

Comment: Well, 4.3.0 is only release candidate now, so spring will probably update dependencies when it's released. As for why it's been done so is hard to tell and I cannot find any information regarding this. Probably just a refactoring to have a cleaner API. Again, I'm sure spirng will update to 4.3.0 when it's released, for now just stick to stable version.

Comment: On the other side, upgrading Spring is another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since Hibernate **4.3.x**, the JtaPlatform class is refactored to a new package. To fix it,you need to upgrade your spring version to **4.1.x** latest release.Below I am providing the code for **pom.xml** which I have tested for my own application.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
```